# Can i Implement a Cache in Azure Statless fabric service

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I chosen stateless service fabric. I need to put AzureToken in a cache, But not able to get Httpcontext.Current.Session object directly. Any otherway to implement a cache in stateless service fabric. if it so,
that cache is also available in across all the nodes? .
Thanks Advance.

Comment: Can't you add a stateful service to hold the tokens?